# How do we use OpenID with AzureAD to authenticate to SharePoint Office 365 API

Tags: development, oauth, openid-connect-protocol

I need to have a user context available to get a list of SP lists based on permissions. I've wired up `Startup.Auth.cs` with `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`. I've granted the SharePoint permissions in the Azure portal. At this point, I  can sign the user into Azure AD.

I'm using the C# `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace, but I'm not sure how to get the Token from the login and use it for a call to SharePoint.

`var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(email, securePassword);
context.Credentials = credential;`

I know how to do the above if I had the user's email and password, but I've not had any luck tracking down a code sample for this scenario.